# setup ssh a special kind of ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, web-server, ssh-tunnel

Ok so I have run into a pickle. I have a web application that I really need to demo this weekend. I can't demo it unless my sysadmin (who is off work) takes down client SSL authentication. There is however a path that information can flow over. The web application is on server A. I have another server B that can ssh into server A. Server B is also publically accessible. I can run the application on server A locally (on localhost that is) but I can't run the application on server B at all. My idea is to somehow use SSH to allow server B to proxy request to localhost:8000 on server A. I do not know how to do this however. Any ideas? I have root on neither of these machines mind you.

UPDATE:
Our sysadmin was a saint and took time out of his weekend to VPN in from his house to help us out.

edit:
I can also ssh from server A into server B so it might be possible to setup a reverse SSH tunnel of somesort.

edit2:
also only 1 client needs to be able to use the application and this client is trustworthy and can cooperate with me to some extent.

Comment: Apparently you don't have a sysadmin when you need one.

Comment: Or he has a sysadmin who knows better than to work weekends because a developer decided he has an urgent demo during the weekend without telling him in advance. Lack of planning does not constitute an emergency. :-)

Comment: ^this unfortunately. I fully admit to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't said what SSH client you're using, I'm going to assume OpenSSH. You can in principle do the same with PuTTY though, although the specifics will be different.

There are three possible ways to do this, depending on what's going to be easier for you.

### Method 1: One SSH tunnel through Server B

The most straight-forward method is if you can get your webapp on Server A to listen in a way that is reachable by Server B, for example by not binding to localhost but to the internal IP address of the network card. In this example, the server listens on port 8000, and ServerA has the internal hostname "serverA.internal.example.com" You can then do something like:

```
client$ ssh -L 12345:serverA.internal.example.com:8000 serverB.external.example.com
```

Then, the machine running ssh will be able to access the webapp on `http://localhost:12345/`

This method requires the client to have SSH to Server B.

### Method 2: Daisy-chain two SSH tunnels

If you are not able to change your webapp to listen on anything but localhost, you will have to do something like this:

```
client$ ssh -L 12345:localhost:23456 serverB.external.example.com
serverB$ ssh -L 23456:localhost:8000 serverA.internal.example.com
```

This will daisy-chain two SSH tunnels, letting you access the webapp from the client on `http://localhost:12345`

This method would require the client to have access to Servers B and A. You can get away with only letting the client have access to Server B by setting up the second half of the tunnel yourself in advance.

### Method 3: Two SSH tunnels and a port forward

If you absolutely can not give the client an SSH account, even after [locking the client down to only permit SSH tunneling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding), there remains method 3.

```
yourbox$ ssh -L '*:12345:localhost:23456' serverB.external.example.com
serverB$ ssh -L 23456:localhost:8000 serverA.internal.example.com
```

Note the addition of *: to the first tunnel. This makes it so that the first SSH tunnel running from *your* machine (not the client's machine) binds a listen port to any network interface, which would probably be a LAN IP address in your case. You can then get your router to port forward to this port on your computer.

So, in essence, the client would connect to the router's WAN IP, which would DNAT it to your machine's LAN IP, which would let the client speak to OpenSSH on your box, which would shove it down an SSH tunnel bound for server B's localhost:12345, which would shove it down another SSH tunnel down to server A's localhost:23456, and you're done.

Keep in mind that this eposes your webapp to anybody who happens to know the IP address of your router and the port number.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is of course permissible to use the same port numbers on either side of the tunnel, I've chosen to use different port numbers for clarity.

Comment: I can't bind to anything but localhost and it seems like I would have to give the client my password for server B to use method 2. That is something I don't think I can do nor do I want to. Other than that it seems like method 2 could work.

Comment: OK, if you don't want to give the client access to your servers, I'll have to suggest a Method 3. Just a moment...

Comment: I just realised something. You said Server B was "publically accessible". Does that mean you can talk to any port on that server without your sysadmin opening any ports? In that case you can pare down the Rube-Goldberg madness that is Method 3, and just use a single SSH tunnel from Server B to Server A binding on *.

Comment: Method 2 seems worked for me from my laptop. I cannot setup port forwarding. I do not know if I can use any port I want to but apparently right now I just used port 12345 to use method 2. Does that count?

Comment: Can you explain method 3 version 2 a bit more? I am not understanding

Comment: This was super helpful for a bit(I was able to use the application from my laptop for a while). My sysadmin came though and helped us!!! Thank you so much!